# Replacing code that used a listbox to code that uses a Y/N Table

Tags: vba, excel

So before, my code ran with all the states that were checked. Now, I have to replace the listbox with a table with a column of states, and a column of Y/N. I want the code to run with all the states that have a Y next to them.

Code before:

```
For Item = 0 To Sheets("Documentation").ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If Sheets("Documentation").ListBox1.Selected(Item) = True Then
        If Sheets("Documentation").ListBox1.List(Item) = "Compact" Then
            Range("Statename") = "CO"
            stname = "C"
        Else
            Range("Statename") = Sheets("Documentation").ListBox1.List(Item)
            stname = Range("Statename")
        End If
        ....
        ....
        ....
     End If
Next
```

I'm not sure how to make this a for loop. My attempt:

```
For cell in range(Range of Y/N Column)
     If Range(cell) = "Y"  Then
         If Range("rowofcell,columnofcell - 1") = "Compact" Then
                Range("Statename") = "CO"
                stname = "C"
            Else
                Range("Statename") = Range("rowofcell,columnofcell - 1")
                stname = Range("Statename")
            End If
            ....
            ....
            ....
         End If
    Next
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm taking a little creative license since you didn't mention where your data is located and how the output is being used.  Starting with data like this:

[image]

---

Run this macro:

```
Sub loopList()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim StateName As Range
    Dim stname As String

    For Each cell In Range("B2:B8")
        If cell.Value = "Y" Then
            Set StateName = Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 1)

            If cell.Offset(0, -1) = "Compact" Then
                StateName.Value = "CO"
                stname = "C"
            Else
                StateName = cell.Offset(0, -1)
                stname = StateName.Value
            End If
         End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Output:

[image]

Comment: if the state has a N, move onto the next state. If the state has a Y, cell C2 should change to a corresponding value, and then a bunch of other code should be executed using C2. After that is done, check if the next state has a Y and repeat the process. 

I have some code that works no matter where in the list the state with a Y is located
, but it stops looping after it finds a state with a Y.